# Approximation of a two-variable function by tensor products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces and $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

We know that, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, there exist $k_n \in \mathbb{N}$ and continuous functions $f^{(1,n)}_i$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, k_n\}$, on $X$ and continuous functions $f^{(2,n)}_i$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, k_n\}$, on $Y$, such that

> $$ \sup_{x \in X, y \in Y } \bigg| f(x,y) - \sum_{i=1}^{k_n} f^{(1,n)}_i(x) f^{(2,n)}_i(y) \bigg| < \frac{1}{n} .$$

Is it possible to choose these functions such that

> $$ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}   k_n < + \infty, $$
>   $$   \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \sup_{i \in \{1, \ldots, k_n\}}\sup_{x \in X} \Big| f^{(1,n)}_i(x) \Big| < +\infty, \quad \quad \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 
>  \sup_{i \in \{1, \ldots, k_n\}}\sup_{y \in Y} \Big| f^{(2,n)}_i(y) \Big| < +\infty \quad ? $$

Comment: Doesn't one use partions of unity multiplied by values of $f$ to get those univariate functions, and doesn't that show that the answer is yes?

Comment: Sorry - partitions of unity...

Comment: @Dirk Sorry can you give more details? One possible choice of partition of unity of $X \times Y$ consists of products of univariate functions of $X$ and $Y$. But after multiplying each function by $f$ ( not necessarily a product of univariate functions), the product itself is still not necessarily a product of univariate functions...

Comment: @DirkWerner I just realised that, in my proof, I also need the sequence $k_n$ to be bounded in $n$. Do you think that partition of unity still works? Thanks.

Comment: @Richard Do you want $k_n\leq n$ or some other bound will suffice?

Comment: @Piotr ideally I would want $k_n$ to be uniformly bounded to get my desired rate of convergence in my proof. Alternatively, I can require $ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \sum_{i=1}^{k_n} \sup_{x \in X} \Big| f^{(1,n)}_i(x) \Big| < +\infty$

Comment: @Richard I think uniform bout of $k_n$ by a constant independent of $n$ is not possible. Also the second estimate seems not possible. However, $\sup_x\sup_n\sum_i|f_i^{(1,n)}(x)|<\infty$ is more likely to be true. Would it be enough? That is my rough guess.

Comment: @Piotr Yes, that is enough as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Richard: Do you require Piotr's condition only for $x$ (that can be done) or also for $y$ (I don't see that...)?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the function $f$ consider the associated function $F: X \to C(Y)$, which is continuous. Let $\varepsilon>0$, and for each $x_0$ take a neighbourhood $U(x_0)$ where $\|F(x)-F(x_0)\|<\varepsilon$, from this cover of $X$ take a finite subcover $U(x_1),\dots,U(x_n)$ and a partition of unity $f_1,\dots,f_n$ subordinate to this subcover. Write $g_k=F(x_k)$ and $g(x,y)= \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) g_k(y)$. Then $\|f-g\|\le3\varepsilon$, all $f_k$ satisfy $0\le f_k\le 1$ and of course $\sum f_k = 1$. Also $\|g_k\|\le \|f\|$. So the bounds on $f_k$ and $g_k$ and the sum condition on the $f_k$ are ok.

However, in general one cannot have the sum condition $\sup_y \sum |g_k(y)| < \infty$ as well. If so, one would have an estimate for the ``weak $\ell_2$-norm'' $\sup_y (\sum |g_k(y)|^2)^{1/2}$ as well  and likewise for $\sup_x [\dots]$. In terms of tensor norms this means that the injective tensor norm (corresponding to the sup-norm of $f$) is equivalent to Grothendieck's Hilbertian norm $w_2$, defined on the tensor product of two Banach spaces as follows: If $\|(x_j)\|_2^w := \sup_{x^*\in B_{E^*}} \|(x^*(x_j))\|_{\ell_2}$, put $\|u\|_{w_2}=\inf \|(x_j)\|_2^w\|(y_j)\|_2^w$, where the infimum is taken over all representations of the tensor $u\in E\otimes F$ as $u=\sum x_k \otimes y_k$. The punchline here is that for spaces of continuous functions, the Hilbertian norm is equivalent to the projective norm by Grothendieck's inequality. Hence the injective and the projective tensor norms would be equivalent on spaces of continuous functions, which they aren't.